# How to execute programs from geany using the GUI?

Tags: ide

well i recently installed geany .. the ide is great and worked great for python programs ,
but when i try executing c/c++ programs from the executed button i get an error saying ./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./rsa2: not found    ( rsa is the name of my program ) 
well i did try googling out but could find a case like mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a program, you need to compile it. 
By default, the compile key in geany is F8.
Then, you can run the program. (F5)
You can define flags in project>properties (click on the "construct" tab).

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing F8 and F5 and the problem was same as yours. But then i did build, compile and run and it worked.(This post may help someone !!)